# Is there a mathamatical proof that sematic error detection system design is imposible to design?

Tags: computer-science, semantics

In the video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k6U-i4gXkLM&t=2638s

the professor (at about 43:50) says that "you would love to have a system that spots your semantic errors, but its not possible".
Is there a mathematical proof for that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: Should it be posted in mathematics?

Comment: There is no need of a mathematical proof, it is an evident fact. The meaning of the result of a program is in the *mind* of the reader and the programmer. A semantic error is two minds (user and programmer) disagreeing on an interpretation. What does `x*(1-s)` mean? Is it really how the seller meant to discount the products? A computer cannot tell. More advanced type systems give you much more semantic (see Curry-Howard corr) but the atoms of semantic are still free (having A->B only tells you that B cannot be false if A is true but when and how the prop/pred A is true is up to your semantic).

Comment: @MargaretBloom thanks it was very elaborate.